# Distinct, Join and If / As MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

This is the problem - how do I make the following work WITHOUT using UNION or a second select query?

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(t.tid), IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job
                      FROM smf_posts p
                        LEFT JOIN smf_topics t ON (p.topic_id=t.tid)"
```

So that when I add in the WHERE statements it can recognize the if / as of last_job?

For instance in the WHERE below

WHERE last_job < 2000

In other words, I want this "IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job"
to be recognized by the time it reaches "WHERE last_job < 2000". With my current code it does not follow "IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job".

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please reformulate "it can recognize the if / else of last_job" in more common English?

Comment: I'm tempted to leave an answer than you can leave it as it is. No UNION, no second SELECT query or subquery. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I said at the bottom "With my current code it does not follow "IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job"." When I put the WHERE statement it does not go by the IF / AS, understand?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is executed first, before the `SELECT` list is populated. That's why you can't use the alias (the `last_job` from `AS last_job`) in the `WHERE`.

Comment: That makes sense ypercube, however that reverts back to my original question... "how do I make the following work WITHOUT using UNION or a second select query?"

Comment: @MySQLHelp: If you don't explain better what you want, then nobody can help you. Try posting some data from the two tables and the desired output.

Comment: From which table are the `last_job` and `last_job2` fields ?

Comment: last_job and last_job2 fields comes from smf_topics. Not sure what else to explain about it. When smf_topics is looked up it should look to see if there are any rows where last_job2 is less than 2000 if there are any then when last_job is read the value should be replaced with last_job2. Therefore when WHERE is arrived at in the query last_job will also have last_job2 as its value. Does that explain better?

Comment: So, you want to show `smf_topics.id` for those rows that `lastjob` is smaller than 2000? Or for all rows?

Comment: All rows - I just saw your edit below and I think that did the trick thanks!

Comment: When you have an outer join (like `LEFT OUTER` you have), it's not good to use the fields from the RIGHT table in the WHERE conditions. The LEFT join is actually cancelled.

Comment: Thanks so then how do you recommend using the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess. Do you want this?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.tid)
     , IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job
FROM smf_posts p
  LEFT JOIN smf_topics t ON (p.topic_id=t.tid)
WHERE IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) < 2000
```

or perhaps this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.tid)
     , IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) AS last_job
FROM smf_posts p
  LEFT JOIN smf_topics t
    ON (p.topic_id=t.tid)
    AND IF(last_job2 <= 2000, last_job2, last_job) < 2000
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt but neither works because in Where last_job should pick up the value from the previous If / AS but it does not.